# Rails routes redirect with Bound Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my routes im doing:

```
get 'category/products/:product_hash(/:ref)',
  to: redirect('/new_path/products/%{product_hash}%{ref}', status: 301)

get 'new_path/products/:product_hash(/:ref)',
  to: 'products#new', as: :new_product, defaults: {ref: 'print'}
```

It isn't working with %{ref}, it returns:

"key{ref} not found"

How can i make this "**ref**" optional parameter in my redirect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to give your redirection route a default value for `ref` as well. Note that empty string is a valid value, if you want the default to be blank.

You might also want to move the `/` outside the brackets - it's fine to have a trailing slash, and moving it will help to ensure that your defaults are passed through correctly (i.e. otherwise you would need to append the `/`, and there may be cases where you end up with a double slash). So you could end up with something like:

```
get 'category/products/:product_hash/(:ref)',
  to: redirect('/new_path/products/%{product_hash}/%{ref}', status: 301), defaults: {ref: ''}

get 'new_path/products/:product_hash/(:ref)',
  to: 'products#new', as: :new_product, defaults: {ref: 'print'}
```